# mongoose isValidObjectId() always returns false

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having a weird issue with isValidObjectID() in mongoose, which appeared after I added TypeScript to my Node project and had to update mongoose as a result, and force mongoose to use an updated mongodb dependency by overriding it in `package.json`

```
"overrides": {
    "mongoose": {
      "mongodb": "^4.3.0"
    }
```

After doing that, all my tests that involved isValidObjectID() started to fail. I'm pretty sure what's being passed to isValidObjectID() is a valid mongodb object id, but it still returns false.

```
import { isValidObjectId, Types } from "mongoose";

isValidObjectId('61cc6d8676a69c41fd3408ea'); // returns false
isValidObjectId(new Types.ObjectId('61cc6d8676a69c41fd3408ea')); // returns false
```

I even tried some of the examples from the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/mongoose.html#mongoose_Mongoose-isValidObjectId) that are supposed to return true, but they all return false!

```
isValidObjectId(new Types.ObjectId()); // returns false!
isValidObjectId('0123456789ab'); // returns false
isValidObjectId(6); // returns false
```

whereas according to the documentation, they all should return true.

I'm using mongoose version 6.1.9 , and due to package.json override, mongoose is using mongodb version 4.3.1

Comment: _"I'm using mongoose version 8.4.0"_ - there is no such version yet, and `6.2.x` is the latest.

Comment: @prasad_ you're right, I wrote my NPM's version by mistake. Updated the post now. thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently this was a bug in mongoose 6.1.9
updated to mongoose 6.2.0 and it's fixed now